# Sufficient Statistic-Estimation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have been given pdf $f$(x,$\theta$)=$\frac{\theta}{x^{2}}$, where $0<\theta \le x <\infty $ and I have to find the sufficient statistic. I have a ${({X}_{i})}_{i=1}^{n}$ i.i.d sample.

So joint pdf will be $\prod_{i=1}^{n}$$\frac{\theta}{{x}_{i}^{2}}$. As $\theta$ is independent of i, we can factorize the joint pdf into two functions, one being $\theta^{n}$ and $\prod_{i=1}^{n}$$\frac{1}{{x}_{i}^{2}}$. From here I am not sure how to apply factorization theorem and what is the sufficient statistic. Is it n? If anyone can guide, i'll be grateful.

Comment: This is to let you know that there's a separate website called Cross Validated (or, Statistics Stack Exchange) where you can post problems relevant to Statistics (e.g. this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint pdf should be
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\theta}{x_i^2} I_{\{x_i \ge \theta\}} = \theta^n I_{\{\min\{x_i\} \ge \theta\}}\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{{x}_{i}^{2}}$$
where $I$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Therefore your sufficient statistic is $\min\{ x_i \}$.

Comment: Thanks @NeatMath

Comment: I am also trying to find the method of moment estimator for $\theta$ but first moment of the distribution does not exist as $\int_{\theta}^{\infty}\frac{\theta}{x}$ diverges. In fact none of the moments exist. So am i wrong in stating that MOM estimator does not exist?

Comment: @shaheryarrafi I believe you are right to say that.